# Error using datebox with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

Found this Datebox example on internet but when I copy the code in a separate html file this doesn't seem to work on any browser. Please suggest how to use datebox and what is the problem with the code?

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ktbcP/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />       
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="mydate">Some Date</label>
            <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/css/jquery-mobile-fluid960.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />       
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js">     </script>      
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="mydate">Some Date</label>
        <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
  </div>   
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Where was I lacking?And one more question : Can you suggest how do I change the color of the calendar? Which particular property in css is used to give it black color?

Comment: Open the fiddle and notice there are few resources mentioned on left side panels. )Under External Resources heading)

Comment: The black color is because of the theme being used in it. (IN this case, it is data-theme ="a". Play around yourself with themes - http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html

Comment: The easiest way to understand/copy what is going on inside a fiddle is to copy the actual HTML output i.e. Right click on RESULT panel and save the source code. This way you will not miss out on any external resources etc.